# Python scrapy to extract specific Xpath fields

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am having following structure (sample). i am using scrapy to extract the details. I need to extract the fields of 'href' and text like 'Accounting'. I am using the following code. I am new to Xpath. any help to extarct the specific fields .

```
<div class = 'something'>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/a/accounting-job-titles.htm" data-component="link" data-source="inlineLink" data-type="internalLink" data-ordinal="1">Accounting</a></li> 

        <li><a href="http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/a/admin-job-titles.htm" data-component="link" data-source="inlineLink" data-type="internalLink" data-ordinal="2">Administrative</a></li> 

        <li><a href="http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-titles/a/advertising-job-titles.htm" data-component="link" data-source="inlineLink" data-type="internalLink" data-ordinal="3">Advertising</a></li> 

        <li><a href="http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/fl/airline-industry-jobs.htm" data-component="link" data-source="inlineLink" data-type="internalLink" data-ordinal="4">Airline</a></li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

My code is:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider

from jobfetch.items import JobfetchItem

from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.loader import XPathItemLoader
from scrapy.contrib.loader.processor import Join, MapCompose


class JobFetchSpider(BaseSpider):
"""Spider for regularly updated livingsocial.com site, San Francisco Page"""
name = "Jobsearch"
    allowed_domains = ["jobsearch.about.com/"]
    start_urls = ['http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-titles/fl/job-titles-a-z.htm']

    def parse(self, response):
    count = 0
    for sel in response.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/article/div[2]/ul[1]'):
        item = JobfetchItem()
        item['title'] = sel.extract()
        item['link'] = sel.extract()
        count = count+1
        print item

    yield item
```

Comment: Glad to see people actually using that newcoder.io scrapy tutorial.

Comment: @alecxe - Yeah. its easy to do it using BeautifulSoup. But we should learn new technologies. I dont have much time to go through xpath basics. I am getting the entire html. I am not familiar with parsing it via xpath or  HtmlxpathSelector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems you have in the code:

- `yield item` should be inside the loop since you are instantiating items there
- the xpath you have is pretty messy and not quite reliable since it heavily relies on the elements location inside parent tags and starts from almost the top parent of the document
- your xpath is incorrect - it should go down to the `a` elements inside `li` inside `ul`
- `sel.extract()` would only give you that `ul` element extracted

For the sake of an example, use a `CSS selector` here to get to the `li` tags:

```
import scrapy

from jobfetch.items import JobfetchItem


class JobFetchSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "Jobsearch"
    allowed_domains = ["jobsearch.about.com/"]
    start_urls = ['http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-titles/fl/job-titles-a-z.htm']

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.css('article[itemprop="articleBody"] div.expert-content-text > ul > li > a'):
            item = JobfetchItem()
            item['title'] = sel.xpath('text()').extract()[0]
            item['link'] = sel.xpath('@href').extract()[0]
            yield item
```

Running the spider produces:

```
{'link': u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/a/accounting-job-titles.htm', 'title': u'Accounting'}
{'link': u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/a/admin-job-titles.htm', 'title': u'Administrative'}
...
{'link': u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/fl/yacht-job-titles.htm', 'title': u'Yacht Jobs'}
```

---

FYI, we could have used `xpath()` also:

```
//article[@itemprop="articleBody"]//div[@class="expert-content-text"]/ul/li/a
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below script to extract the data as you want to scrape.

```
In [1]: response.xpath('//div[@class="expert-content-text"]/ul/li/a/text()').extract()
Out[1]: 

[u'Accounting',
 u'Administrative',
 u'Advertising',
 u'Airline',
 u'Animal',
 u'Alternative Energy',
 u'Auction House',
 u'Banking',
 u'Biotechnology',
 u'Business',
 u'Business Intelligence',
 u'Chef',
 u'College Admissions',
 u'College Alumni Relations and Development ',
 u'College Student Services',
 u'Construction',
 u'Consulting',
 u'Corporate',
 u'Cruise Ship',
 u'Customer Service',
 u'Data Science',
 u'Engineering',
 u'Entry Level Jobs',
 u'Environmental',
 u'Event Planning',
 u'Fashion',
 u'Film',
 u'First Job',
 u'Fundraiser',
 u'Healthcare/Medical',
 u'Health/Safety',
 u'Hospitality',
 u'Human Resources',
 u'Human Services / Social Work',
 u'Information Technology (IT)',
 u'Insurance',
 u'International Affairs / Development',
 u'International Business',
 u'Investment Banking',
 u'Law Enforcement',
 u'Legal',
 u'Maintenance',
 u'Management',
 u'Manufacturing',
 u'Marketing',
 u'Media',
 u'Museum',
 u'Music',
 u'Non Profit',
 u'Nursing',
 u'Outdoor ',
 u'Public Administration',
 u'Public Relations',
 u'Purchasing',
 u'Radio',
 u'Real Estate ',
 u'Restaurant',
 u'Retail',
 u'Sales',
 u'School',
 u'Science',
 u'Ski and Snow Jobs',
 u'Social Media',
 u'Social Work',
 u'Sports',
 u'Television',
 u'Trades',
 u'Transportation',
 u'Travel',
 u'Yacht Jobs']


In [1]: response.xpath('//div[@class="expert-content-text"]/ul/li/a/@href').extract()

Out[2]: 
[u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/a/accounting-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/a/admin-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-titles/a/advertising-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/fl/airline-industry-jobs.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/fl/animal-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/fl/alternative-energy-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/fl/auction-house-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/fl/banking-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/fl/biotechnology-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/a/business-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/fl/business-intelligence-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://culinaryarts.about.com/od/culinaryfundamentals/a/whatisachef.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/fl/college-admissions-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/fl/college-alumni-relations-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/fl/college-student-service-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/a/construction-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/fl/consulting-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/a/c-level-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/fl/cruise-ship-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/fl/customer-service-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/fl/data-science-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/a/engineering-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/best-jobs/a/best-entry-level-jobs.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/fl/environmental-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://eventplanning.about.com/od/eventcareers/tp/corporateevents.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/fl/fashion-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/fl/film-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/justforstudents/a/first-job-list.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/fl/fundraiser-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/a/health-care-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/a/health-safety-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/a/hospitality-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://humanresources.about.com/od/HR-Roles-And-Responsibilities/fl/human-resources-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/fl/human-services-social-work-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/a/it-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/a/insurance-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/fl/international-affairs-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/fl/international-business-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/fl/investment-banking-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/fl/law-enforcement-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/a/legal-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/a/maintenance-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/fl/management-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/a/manufacturing-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/fl/marketing-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/a/media-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/fl/museum-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/fl/music-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/a/nonprofit-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/fl/nursing-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/fl/outdoor-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/fl/public-administration-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/a/public-relations-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/fl/purchasing-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/fl/radio-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/a/real-estate-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/fl/restaurant-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/fl/retail-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/fl/sales-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/fl/high-school-middle-school-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/a/science-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/skiandsnowjobs/a/skijob2_2.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/a/social-media-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/a/social-work-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/fl/sports-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/fl/television-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/fl/trades-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/a/transportation-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/fl/travel-job-titles.htm',
 u'http://jobsearch.about.com/od/job-title-samples/fl/yacht-job-titles.htm']
```

Comment: Let me check it man . I will let you know soon. Give me some minutes.

Comment: First of all, example is from the shell, though clearly the OP is experiencing issues with looping over `li` tags and extracting `a` tag's href and texts and extracting items in the spider. Also, this doesn't correspond to what the OP was asking about - you are missing `@href`s.

Comment: @anandhakumar : response.xpath('//div[@class="expert-content-text"]/ul/li/a/ I understand. But to iterate it in a loop and get both text and href at single shot what I have to give. In simple sense, I am unable to extarct another xpath or portion from the main xpath

Comment: @alecxe - As anandhakumar mentioned, response.xpath('//div[@class="expert-content-text"]/ul/li/a/ I understand. But to iterate it in a loop and get both text and href at single shot what I have to give. In simple sense, I am unable to extarct another xpath or portion from the main xpath

Comment: @user3116355 do you see, there is an another answer here, complete tested solution :)